# Seeking library that reads/writes shapefiles to use with .net core 2.2?

Tags: shapefile, c#, software-recommendations, .net

Previously I used to use Easy Gis .net. Now we have a .netcore 2.2 project and I need to read/write Shapefiles. I have googled for 2 hours and I didn't find anything. I also tried to use dotspatial and easy gis on .netcore 2.2 and it failed.

Comment: How did dotspatial fail on .net core 2.2?

Comment: dotspatial not supporting .net core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile/2.0.0
https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile

Example:
https://seydahatipoglu.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/how-to-read-a-shapefile-in-nettopologysuite/

Licence:
https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v3-(lgpl-3)

Comment: please provide short summarys of your links as they may become invalid someday.

Comment: i did it with netTopologySuite

Answer (score 0):

i did it with NetTopologySuite.IO just add it from nuget 
Install-Package NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile -Version 2.0.0
and this is a sample code from my project that convert microsoft sql table to shapefile

```
public async Task GenerateAreaShapeFile(int areaId)
    {
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Parcel, LandUseCategory> parcles = _db.Parcels.Where(p => p.AreaId == areaId && p.IsDeleted == false)
                .Include(p => p.User).Include(p => p.ParcelMediaFiles).Include(p => p.SurveyArea).Include(p => p.LandUse).ThenInclude(l => l.Category);

        string tmpName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        DirectoryInfo shpDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_appSet.TempDir, tmpName));
        shpDir.Create();

        int curCount = await parcles.CountAsync();
        int i = 0;
        int totalCount = (int)(curCount * 1.05);

        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
        List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>();
        string crsDirStr = "";


        foreach (Parcel p in parcles)
        {
            Polygon geom = p.geom;

            IAttributesTable attributes = new AttributesTable();
            attributes.Add("Id", p.Id);
            attributes.Add("Serial", p.Serial);
            attributes.Add("Area", p.Area ?? 0);
            attributes.Add("User", p.User?.FullName ?? "");
            attributes.Add("UTime", p.SurveyTime?.ToString() ?? "");
            attributes.Add("LUCategory", p.LandUse?.Category.CategoryName?.ToString() ?? "");
            attributes.Add("LandUse", p.LandUse?.LandUse ?? "");
            attributes.Add("Categ", p.LandUse?.Category.CategoryName ?? "");
            attributes.Add("area", p.SurveyArea?.AreaName ?? "");
            attributes.Add("Hieght", p.BldHeight ?? 0);
            attributes.Add("bldStat", p.BldState ?? "");
            attributes.Add("bldSys", p.BldStrSystem ?? "");
            attributes.Add("elec", p.Elec.ToString());
            attributes.Add("water", p.Water.ToString());
            attributes.Add("saint", p.Sant.ToString());
            attributes.Add("telecom", p.Telecomm.ToString());
            attributes.Add("tLat", p.Lat ?? 0);
            attributes.Add("tLng", p.Lng ?? 0);
            attributes.Add("Notes", p.Notes ?? "");
            attributes.Add("NR", p.NeedReview);
            attributes.Add("NrNote", p.ReviewNotes ?? "");
            attributes.Add("ImageUrl", imageUrl);
            attributes.Add("UseColor", p.LandUse?.Color ?? "");
            attributes.Add("CatColor", p.LandUse?.Category?.Color ?? "");


            Feature feature = new Feature(geom, attributes);
            features.Add(feature);
            i++;
            await _reportHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("GenerateShapeFileProgress", "Add parcels....", p.AreaId, i, totalCount);
        }

        DbaseFileHeader dbaseFileHeader = null;
        try
        {
            dbaseFileHeader = ShapefileDataWriter.GetHeader(features[0], features.Count, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        ShapefileDataWriter shapefileDataWriter = new ShapefileDataWriter(Path.Combine(shpDir.FullName, "ShapeFile.Shp"), gf, Encoding.UTF8)
        {
            Header = dbaseFileHeader
        };
        shapefileDataWriter.Write(features);

        DirectoryInfo crsDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "AppData\\" + crsDirStr));
        if (crsDir.Exists)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in crsDir.GetFiles())
            {
                file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(shpDir.FullName, "ShapeFile" + file.Extension));
            }
        }
        await _reportHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("GenerateShapeFileProgress", "Compressing ShapeFile to Zip", areaId, ++i, totalCount);

        FileInfo[] files = shpDir.GetFiles();
        string zipedFile = Path.Combine(shpDir.FullName, "ShapeFile.zip");
        using FileStream zipFileStream = new FileStream(zipedFile, FileMode.Create);
        using ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: careful with `Hieght` (sic)

Comment: thank you i will fix my spellings